# Yammer Embed config: Feed 'my_all'

Tags: yammer

Is it possible to display feed 'my_all' (https://www.yammer.com/[network]/#/home?type=my_all) within Yammer Embed?

Answer (score 1):

All available embed options are listed here: https://www.yammer.com/widget/configure

There is a "My Feed" option, which is probably the one you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can leave the feed type out and get the My Feed. Yammer Embed offers a number of feed types and for historical reasons these do not match what is available in the Yammer website, including the Discovery or Following feeds.

Comment: On the Yammer website under the tab 'All' I also get posts from groups which I am not member of. If I join one of them I also get the feed in Yammer Embed (My Feed).
I think it is not possible to get the exact same feed like on Yammer website's 'All' tab?

Comment: As I started above it doesn't match what's shown on the site so you can't get the same feed. It may include some items from groups of which you are not a member if it's pulling content from the All Company feed. If you want more options you might be best to post at https://yammer.uservoice.com/ and explain what you'd like to see.